# Delete all visible cookies raises an exception

Tags: python, exception, selenium, cookies

I am using selenium with a python client. When doing selenium.delete_all_visible_cookies I get the exception:

> ERROR: Command execution failure.
>   Please search the forum at
>   http://clearspace.openqa.org for error
>   details from the log window.  The
>   error message is: malformed URI
>   sequence

The log window's error is:

```
error(1254427481456): Exception details: 
message -> malformed URI sequence, 
fileName -> http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js,
lineNumber -> 1169, 
stack -> 
("WSS_GW",[object HTMLDocument])@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1169 
("WSS_GW",".mysite","/",[object HTMLDocument])@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1208 
("WSS_GW",".mysite","/",[object HTMLDocument])@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1213 
("WSS_GW",".mysite","/",[object HTMLDocument])@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1236 
("WSS_GW","mysite","/",[object XPCCrossOriginWrapper])@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js:1248 
("","")@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-api.js:2607
("","")@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60 
([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-commandhandlers.js:310 
()@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:112 
(-10)@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:78 
(-10)@http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60 , 
name -> URIError
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the bug: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-712

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, see here: 
http://clearspace.openqa.org/message/68779