# Selenium: Problem with deleting cookies

Tags: python, cookies, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

We are using selenium 2.4 with a python client, and running the scripts on Firefox.
When doing delete_all_visible_cookies we are getting the exception:

> ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window. The error message is: malformed URI sequence

We realized it happens when we have a cookie from a third-party (so we can't change it) that causes the problem. We [asked about it here in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506315/selenium-delete-all-visible-cookies-raises-an-exception) and there is an [open bug of Selenium](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-712) for this problem, but it wasn't fixed yet.

To overcome this problem in the meanwhile we deleted the problematic cookie separately using delete_cookie before doing delete_all_visible_cookies. However, in Selenium 2 we are getting this error also for delete_cookie.

We thought it may be because of the cookie's value (something like: WSS_GW=V1z%X%X^^^@C@) so we tried to override it and set it to 0 before deleting the cookie. Then we got the error:

> ERROR: Couldn't delete cookie WSS_GW.

The only explanation I found in the web for this error message is:
[deleteAllVisibleCookies fails if a cookie name contains % character](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=441)
but we have other cookies that contain _ in their name and everything is working fine.

Any idea what can be the problem or how we can overcome it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, we found the 2 problems we have here:

1. The cookie value is problematic, therefore we got the 'malformed URI sequence' error. To solve this problem I set the cookie value to 0 using create_cookie(), before deleting the cookies.
2. There are 2 cookie with the same name and value, but with different domains: one with 'domain.com' and one with 'a.domain.com' (and the script opened http://b.domain.com). I guess that somehow Selenium saw both of the cookies, and after deleting one it still saw a cookie with the same name, so we got the 'Couldn't delete cookie' error. To solve that, (after I changes the value of all these cookies) I deleted the cookie with the domain 'domain.com' using delete_cookie() **without** the recurse parameter, so when I call delete_all_visible_cookies() it was just one cookie with this name.

To summarize, what I did is:

```
for domain in ['.domain.com','a.domain.com','b.domain.com']:
        sel.create_cookie("%s=0"%problematic_cookie,"path=/, domain=%s"%domain)
sel.delete_cookie(problematic_cookie,"path=/, domain=.domain.com") # without recurse
sel.delete_all_visible_cookies()
```

Comment: from where to import this function and module ? i get always problem
`from selenium import delete_all_visible_cookies`
or
`import selenium as sel`
`sel.delete_all_visible_cookies` 

how to import it from where ?
im using the last version of selenium with python 2.7

Comment: I don't have the code here, but as far as I remember, sel is an object of the selenium class (this code snippet isn't using selenium 2).

Comment: At least in Selenium 2, the cookie APIs are part of the webdriver. As such, the APIs might vary per driver. For example the PhantomJS driver has no `delete_all_visible_cookies`.